# Cannot find lpublic library

Tags: c++, cmake, centos

Trying to compile my project on Centos 8.2 using cmake 3.12, im facing with the following error:

> cannot find -lpublic

here is full log:

```
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ .cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ .cpp.o
[ 60%] Linking CXX shared library  .so
[ 60%] Built target myproj
Scanning dependencies of target nist01
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ .cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable  
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpublic
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/nist01.dir/build.make:85: ...] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:105: CMakeFiles/...] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Tried to find something on the internet, but nothing shown up.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like you try to link against the target "public", which is a suspicious target name. It might be `target_link_libraries` command with lowercase `public` instead of uppercase one, like `target_link_libraryies(nist01 public something)` instead of `target_link_libraries(nist01 PUBLIC something)`.

Comment: thanks @adembudak. Actually Im using lowercase, but you points to the correct place, it was gone after I removed public keyword.